# Fetching values from GridView to edit in asp.net web application

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to update gridview values, but I am getting error saying:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

I want to fetch values of row I selected for edit to update that values in my database and to display edited vales in gridView.

Below is my code.

```
    .aspx file
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  
            OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" DataFormatString="{0:0.##}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserKey" HeaderText="UserKey" DataFormatString="{0:0.##}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Value" DataFormatString="{0:0.##}" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="updateQuery" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [UserID], [UserKey], [Value] FROM [FirstTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


    .aspx.cs file:
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        try
        {
            String UserID = (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            Response.Write(UserID);

            string updateSQL;
            updateSQL = "UPDATE FirstTable SET UserID = @UserID, UserKey = @UserKey, Value = @Value WHERE ID = @ID";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", "aaa");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserKey", "bbb");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "ccc");
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            // GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            GridView1.DataBind();
            BindData();
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write(er);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an update panel in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are accessing wrong columns
first 2 cells has edit button and delete button and 3rd cell has ID so your userID is in 4th cell. so you have to access that cell

```
 String UserID = (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
```